# How to have tmux apply an option only when vim is not running?

Tags: bash, vim, terminal, vi, tmux

I would like to have an option in the tmux configuration file to be activated only if vim is not running in the current panel/window. In particular, the line is the following:

```
bind-key -n MouseDown2Pane run "tmux set-buffer \"$(xclip -o -sel primary)\"; tmux paste-buffer"
```

which allows me to use the middle click to paste directly from the primary clipboard to tmux. It works great, the only problem is that it has a weird behaviour inside vim (pasting in wrong place, strange skipping of lines...). If I comment out that line, pasting with middle click into vim works as espected, but I lose the pasting functionality in tmux, obviously.

So, my question is: how do I make tmux apply that keybinding ONLY if vim is not running?

By doing some research, I found the following approach that looks promising, but I cannot make it work.

```
is_vim="ps -o state= -o comm= -t '#{pane_tty}' \
| grep -iqE '^[^TXZ ]+ +(\\S+\\/)?g?(view|n?vim?x?)(diff)?$'"

if-shell "$is_vim" {command here}
```

Edit: Alternatively, I would also be happy to have the `"tmux set-buffer \"$(xclip -o -sel primary)\"; tmux paste-buffer"` command to work properly when pasting in vim. But that, for some reason, looks like a more difficult task.

Comment: What does that command do when not working properly in vim?

Comment: @jeremysprofile It behaves weirdly. It actually pastes what's in the buffer, but it truncates the first letters and puts it not under the cursor, but 2 or 3 lines after. It also scrolls down the view 2 or 3 lines. This happens if I am in normal mode in vim, while in insert mode it works correctly. But with that line commented out in the .tmux.conf file, the pasting works correctly also in normal mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your problem, you can either use something like `#{?#{m:\*vim\*,#{pane_current_command}},0,1}` to invert the match, or you can use the second argument of `if-shell` instead of the first, so you would do `if -F '...' '' 'mycommand'` where the second argument is just empty.

`if-shell` arguments ARE tmux commands, but they do need to be one argument. So you need to put them in quotes - you will want something like:

`bind -n MouseDown2Pane if -F '#{?#{m:\*vim\*,#{pane_current_command}},0,1}' 'run "xclip -o -sel primary | tmux load-buffer - ; tmux paste-buffer"'`

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this is not working, because tmux is still intercepting the keybinding even when vim is open, and instead than doing the weird paste action, it just does nothing. It does not show the default paste behaviour that it has when that line is uncommented.

Comment: What default paste behaviour? vim's? If you want tmux to send the mouse key press through to vim when it is running, you will need to put "send -M" in the false side of the if command, at the moment you have it doing nothing.

Comment: By false side I mean add another argument to the command above with "send -M" (including the quotes).

Comment: Which one is the false side of the command? Sorry, I don't know at all this syntax and I don't really know where to look. Thanks for your help! EDIT: oh ok, you answered already, nevermind!!

Comment: Yes!! The command ``bind -n MouseDown2Pane if -F '#{?#{m:*vim*,#{pane_current_command}},0,1}' 'run "xclip -o -sel primary | tmux load-buffer - ; tmux paste-buffer"' "send -M"`` does exactly what I wanted! Thank you VERY much Nicholas!!

Answer (score 2):

Above has the right idea, but it would be quicker to use pane_current_command instead of a shell command, something like:

if -F '#{m:*vim*,#{pane_current_command}}' ...

Also I would recommend using "xclip...|tmux loadb -" instead of set-buffer because then you don't run into problems with shell special characters in the clipboard.

Comment: Hi Nicholas, thanks for your helpful answer. I tried doing this: `bind -n MouseDown2Pane if -F '#{m:*vim*,#{pane_current_command}}' run "xclip -o -sel primary | tmux load-buffer - ; tmux paste-buffer" `, however, I have 2 problems. The first one is that I would like that command to be executed when vim is NOT running, while like that the if statement is activated when vim is running. How do I do that (sorry for the n00b question)? The second is that the command written like that does not work anymore, tmux says **unknown command xclip**, why?

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt checks every time the `.tmux.conf` file is sourced, which is (generally) only when first making a tmux session.

You need to have it checked each time you run the command. Fortunately, this is as simple as rearranging the order. Here is an example:

```
bind-key -n C-k if-shell 'test #{window_panes} -gt 1' 'select-pane -t :.-1' 'next-window'
```

Here, `Ctrl+k` checks if I have multiple panes in my window. If I do, I go to the next pane. If I do not, I go to the next window.

I'm not positive `$is_vim` can be a variable in your bind instead of fully written out, you'll have to test that, but it should look like this:

```
bind-key -n MouseDown2Pane if-shell "ps -o state= -o comm= -t '#{pane_tty}' \
| grep -iqE '^[^TXZ ]+ +(\\S+\\/)?g?(view|n?vim?x?)(diff)?$'" \
'<whatever it should do when vim is running' \
"tmux set-buffer \"$(xclip -o -sel primary)\"; tmux paste-buffer"
```

Which looks completely terrible and may be slow since it has to run that shell command to test every time you use that button.